# Unity Get surface on an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

So I need to get information on which triangles are on the same surface, right now I compare normals to the original hit point and then select which normals are below an angle threshold.

But obviously now I get normals that are on different surfaces compared to the original one. need help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Surely this question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Comment: @Ruzihm Normals aren't sufficient for this. Two faces with identical normals may not be coplanar. I would check the distance *along the shared normal* between a vertex from each triangle. If that is below some threshold value (`float.Epsilon` is one option), then you may assume that they are coplanar. Put another way, calculate the distance from the origin `0,0,0` to the plane of each triangle. If it's the same (and has the same sign) then they're the same plane.

Comment: @3Dave Yep. you could check (pseudocode) `(1-dot(hit.normal, triangle.normal) < eps && dot(hit.normal, posofsomevertexoftriangle - hit.point) < eps )`. btw I'm not sure if asker will get a notification since your comment had @Ruzihm.